# Can't get Event Tracking To Work

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, analytics-api

I'm trying to get an event to be tracked (user registration) as a goal.  I DON'T want it to be tracked by an onclick, I want it to be tracked once a PHP event is finished.  Here is my code:

```
if(USER REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL):
<script type="text/javascript">
   var _gaq = _gaq || [];
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'SignUp', 'Registered', 'User Registered']);
</script>
endif;
```

The regular Google Analytics Code is in the footer just before the / body.  On the register page that code is being triggered in the middle of the page.

But the completed goals aren't showing up in Google Analytics, any idea why?

Note: PHP simplified since it doesn't really pertain to this question.

Comment: Does your event code come before or after the regular GA code?

Comment: It comes before, does it have to come after? The way the PHP document is structured it would be very difficult to make the code come after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` - this line is obliterating your existing Google Analytics object and Events cannot be tracked without a call to trackPageView.

## Edit: PHP Code Sample

Sorry, I missed the fact that your GA.js snippet appears after your Event tracking snippet - here is a solution which should resolve the issue:

```
<?php // start of document
if ( USER REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL )
{
    $analytics_addition = "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'SignUp', 'Registered', 'User Registered']);";
}
?>

<!--
      your regular HTML output
-->

<!-- ga.js snippet -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
<?php
    // append event tracking 
    if ( @isset($analytics_addition) && $analytics_addition )
      echo $analytics_addition;
?>
    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- eof ga.js snippet -->
```

Comment: I tried it without that code at the top before I tried this and it still didn't work.  The _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); is at the bottom of the HTML document.

Comment: Ah, then your Google Analytics object doesn't exist yet at all - in which case the GA.js snippet's variable declaration is obliterating the `_gaq` object (which is probably throwing a script error) - your best bet would be to write the Event push to a PHP variable and echo the PHP variable within your GA.js snippet. (added example)

Comment: Good idea, I did something similar, I set a variable to true and then at the bottom of the analytics page I added the script if the variable was true, but your method is more readable so I think i'll do that in the future.